# Sum range over sheets in google spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets

Is it possible to range over sheets in one spreadsheet ?

Ive got sheets: S, A, B, C, D. In S I would like to do (for some cell C4):

```
 =SUM(A:D!C4)
```

To sum C4 in A, B, C, and D. It is doable in google spreadsheet at all ?

Comment: If you don't want to have to enumerate all the cells between "A" and "D" see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60364340/google-sheets-summing-a-cell-over-a-changing-number-of-sheets/60364928#60364928

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You just need to mention the sheet names as well. Though, you'll have to mention each sheet name seperately. Something like this would work

> =SUM(A!C4, B!C4, C!C4, D!C4)

Comment: Use single quotes if the sheet name has space

=SUM('A apple'!C4, 'B ball'!C4, 'C cat'!C4, D!C4)

Comment: If you want to do sum of entire C column from 'Sheet 2' try this: `=SUM('Sheet 2'!C:C)`

Answer (score 3):

I think the answer to this is that it isn't possible on google sheets as yet.

Would love if Sheets actually had similar functionalities.

Comment: This answer is no longer valid as Google Sheets supports this.

Comment: @lacostenycoder not in my testing. What's the syntax for it?

Comment: It absolutely does not support this @lacostenycoder .
=SUM(A!C4, B!C4, C!C4, D!C4) is not the same as =SUM(Sheet2-Sheet1000!C4).

If I'm adding uniquely named sheets, and need every new sheet's C4 to be summed in Sheet1 on a specific Cell, I have to edit it in for every new sheet I add.