# Using a formula across dynamically added sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to work out a formula to sum up values across different sheets for particular rows as in the following:

```
Sheet 1
A   |  B
---------
bob |  3
foo | 14
bar |  7

Sheet 2
A   |  B
---------
bob |  2
foo |  1
bar |  9
```

But with the caveat that a new 'Sheet 3' can be added with relevant data and will automatically be picked up.

How do I go about getting the summed values for each row in each sheet while handling new (properly named) sheets?

```
Results
-------
bob |  5
foo | 15
bar | 16
```

We can assume that the row values are all the same, such as in a named range, People = {bob, foo, bar}.

My attempt has been something like:

```
={People,ARRAYFORMULA('Sheet 1'!B1:B3+'Sheet 2'!B1:B3)}
```

but for new sheets, I would have to manually update the formula by adding in

```
+'Sheet 3'!B1:B3
```

I've tried using `INDIRECT` to dynamically generate the sheet names but it doesn't take an array. I'm guessing that I might have to use

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()
```

in a script, but if I could do it just as a formula, it would be easier to explain to people inheriting the spreadsheet.

Thanks

Comment: similar to this Q: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21081069/sum-range-over-sheets-in-google-spreadsheets

Comment: @MaxMakhrov No, not similar. The answer to that question is essentially what I indicated is my first attempt. It doesn't address how to handle sheets created after the formula is generated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have alternate solution to your problem, using a slightly different approach.
I would suggest pulling all of the data into one results page and summing it there. Then you don't need a massive 'sum' function or a script.

Using `indirect` you can pull information from each sheet, provided the data is in the same cell location on each sheet. If that's not possible you could also use `vlookup` to pull the data. I've shared an example of how I would do this using your numbers.

Syntax for 'bob' value on Sheet1 `=iferror(indirect("'"&C$2&"'!"&"b3"),"")`
where `C$2` is the Sheet name (in this case `Sheet1`) and `B3` is the value for bob on `Sheet1`. Then you can copy this formula across the columns and update your sheet names at the top of the table.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15pB5CclseUetl5zSRPDOR9YA4u6_7TK8RB8CpSxqhnk/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

[Sample File](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13rzhH80v_PurCdpdu0P31TtLHS0_9MR6q9IK02qERTw/edit?usp=sharing)

The workaround is to use a custom function:

[image]

Warning! The function won't refresh automatically. It will refresh if you add and then delete row above it.

Syntax:
`=sumBySheets("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "B1:B3")`

- "Sheet1" — sheet from
- "Sheet2" — sheet to
- "B1:B3" — range address for a sum.

There may be more sheets between Sheet1 and Sheet2:

[image]

The code:

```
function test_sumBySheets()
{
  var sheet1 = 'Sheet1';
  var sheet2 = 'Sheet2';
  var range = 'b1:b3';      
  Logger.log(sumBySheets(sheet1, sheet2, range));    
}

function sumBySheets(sheet1, sheet2, address)
{
  var file = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var s1 = file.getSheetByName(sheet1);
  var s2 = file.getSheetByName(sheet2);

  var i1 = s1.getIndex() - 1; //get sheet indexes
  var i2 = s2.getIndex() - 1;

  var sheets = file.getSheets();

  var result = [];  
  var arrays = [];

  // remember all the data
  for (var i = i1; i <=i2; i++)
  {
    var s = sheets[i];
    var range = s.getRange(address);
    arrays.push(range.getValues());       
  }

  return sumByArrays_(arrays);

}

function sumByArrays_(arrays)
{
  // take array #1
  var arr = arrays[0];
  l = arr.length;
  ll = arr[0].length

  // plus all arrays
  for (var x = 1, xx = arrays.length; x < xx; x++) // loop arrays
  {
    for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) { // loop rows
      for(var ii = 0; ii < ll; ii++) { // loop cells
        arr[i][ii] += arrays[x][i][ii];
      }
    }  
  }

  return arr;

}
```

---

Note:

- please run the function `test_sumBySheets` first and get the permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Been a while, but here's what I ultimately ended up with for my solution.

The following code dynamically loads all sheets associated with the spreadsheet (note that I edited it a bit for readability on SO, might be some typos):

```
// These vars indicate what sheet, column and rows to start 
// the list of sheets.
var main_sheet = 'Sheet1';
var sheet_col = 'A';
var sheet_row_start = 1;

function onEdit(e) {
  // The onEdit trigger is the most useful as it fires most often.
  // Therefore it is more likely to update the list of sheets relatively
  // quickly.
  _set_sheet_cells();
}

function _clear_sheet_cells(num_sheets, sheets_length) {
  // Clear sheet cells, in case number of sheets has dropped.
  var sheet_ctr = Number(num_sheets);
  var stats = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(main_sheet);
  if (sheet_ctr) {
    if (sheet_ctr >= sheets_length) {
      for (var i=0 ; i<sheet_ctr ; i++) {
        stats_sheet.getRange(sheet_col+(sheet_row_start+i)).clearContent();
      }
    }
  }
}

function _get_sheets() {
  // Gather our sheets, can be combined with a regex to prune sheets.
  var out = new Array();
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  for (var i=0 ; i<sheets.length ; i++) {
      out.push( sheets[i].getName() );
    }
  }
  return out  
}

function _set_sheet_cells() {
  var userProperties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
  var num_sheets = Number(userProperties.getProperty('sheet_names'));
  var sheets = _get_sheets();
  if (num_sheets == sheets.length) {
    // Do nothing, no changes, remove if concerned about renaming sheets.
    return;
  }
  _clear_sheet_cells(num_sheets, sheets.length);
  var stats = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(main_sheet);
  for (var j=0 ; j<sheets.length ; j++) {
    // Put one sheet name per row.
    stats_sheet.getRange(sheet_col+(sheet_row_start+j)).setValue(sheets[j]);
  }
  userProperties.setProperty('num_sheets', sheets.length)
}
```

Once I had all the sheets loading dynamically, I just used @cgm990's answer, with the benefit that if I added another sheet to the spreadsheet, it automatically updated all my sums.