# How to highlight duplicate values in a sheet that appears in another sheet

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I know [how to apply conditional formatting if there are duplicate values in a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21899516/highlight-cell-if-value-duplicate-in-same-column-for-google-spreadsheet) and [I know how to use a formula to that references values from multiple sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21081069/sum-range-over-sheets-in-google-spreadsheets); however, what I want to do is apply formatting to a value if it is a duplicate in another sheet.

**Example**: I have sheets "friendlies", "healthcare", "IT" and "marketing" that contain names and contact information. Email addresses are always in column E.

Occasionally someone gets moved from a vertical, healthcare for instance, into the friendlies sheet.

When someone gets added to the friendlies worksheet, I want their email cell (in column E) in the friendlies sheet to turn red to remind me to remove them from the healthcare sheet.

Is it possible create a formula that looks to another sheet for a duplicate? I tried the below with no luck:

*=countif(Healthcare!E:E,E1)>1*, **as well as** *=countif(Healthcare!E:Healthcare!E,E1)>1* **and then finally** *=countif(Healthcare!E:Healthcare!E,Healthcare!E1)>1*

Does anyone have any insights to help?

Comment: Have you tried to incorporate `AND()`?

Comment: The scenario seems rather convoluted. Can you provide a minimal example of what you are trying to accomplish? In any case, check the documentation of  [`match`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093378) to see if you can come up with a solution yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably in connection with security, conditional formatting across sheets can be a bit of a rigmarole but the CF formula rule is very simple if you are prepared to make use of a helper column.

Taking a similar approach to what you tried, the helper column, say `F` should be populated with, in say F1, and copied down to suit:

```
 =countif(healthcare!E:E,E1)+countif(IT!E:E,E1)+countif(marketing!E:E,E1)
```

Then it is just a matter of selecting ColumnE in `friendlies` and Format - Conditional formatting..., Custom formula is and:

```
=F1>0
```

with selecting red formatting of choice and <kbd>Done</kbd>.

An alternative to a helper column is to apply named ranges and INDIRECT:

```
=countif(indirect("hMail"),E1)+countif(indirect("imail"),E1)+countif(indirect("mMail"),E1)
```

`hMail` for example the name for ColumnE in `healthcare`.