# Sum the same cell across the sheets in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, sum, range, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have a sheet for every day in the month. At the end of every month, I need to sum the same cell across all tabs. The following works:

```
=SUM(March31!L2,March30!L2,March29!L2,March28!L2,March26!L2,March25!L2,March24!L2)
```

However, at the end of the month, the formula will be tremendous. Tried the following:

```
=SUM(March31:March1!L2)
```

Doesn't work. Is it even possible?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60364928/

Comment: On a more important note,a sheet for every month/day is a bad bad idea (commonly rookie error). It's preferable to enter all data ina single sheet

Comment: Because It's not maintainable and you'll run into problems like this

Comment: For some of us that have different bills, same name, on different months, it is unclear to me how handling that on a single sheet would be...better...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `SUM(March31:March1!L2)`

That won't work, but you can use kind of a generator:

```
={" "; ARRAYFORMULA("=SUM("&TEXTJOIN(", ", 1, TEXT(ROW(INDIRECT(
 DATEVALUE("2020/01/01")&":"&DATEVALUE("2020/12/31"))), "mmmmd!L2"))&")")}
```

which will give you the full formula you need so all you need to do is copy-paste the cell below:

[image: 0]

### [Spreadsheet demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dD5ETf4-2Sc-7z1EmcuquY7WqZury3jXqI1sQwkntL4/edit#gid=1349786511)

Comment: Thank you! That works! Yes, I am a rookie in the spreadsheet. Please clarify why using a sheet for every month/day is a "bad bad idea"? As for me, it looks well-structured

Comment: Win here is that if you change a number in a sheet the sum will automatically be updated, no refresh shenanigans needed.  The loss being you can't easily change sheets or sheet names post facto...