# Need a Google Sheets formula to sum the same cell across multiple tabs

Tags: google-sheets, formula

I have a Google Sheet with many tabs. Each tab is named with a person's name (first last). Each person's tab has an integer number in cell A1. How can I write a formula in a summary tab that will sum all the integers in all the named tabs, without having to list all the tag names separated by '+'s? I need to do this for many different cells, and there are many named tags, so the effort to build all the formulas takes too long.  Excel has a formula for this, but that formula doesn't work in Google Sheets.

Comment: if you don't use Excel, don't tag with Excel. The two are very different, even if there is some overlap.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60364340/google-sheets-summing-a-cell-over-a-changing-number-of-sheets/60364928#60364928 may be useful

Answer (score 0):

### Workaround

You can create the formula synamically and copy to `A1` but you need SheetTabs names of the Person's like this

```
=CONCATENATE("=",TEXTJOIN(" + ",1, ArrayFormula(SUBSTITUTE("'@'!A1","@",FILTER(C2:C,C2:C<>"")))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create a sheet named `b` (begin) and a sheet named `e` (end) which can be empty. These sheets will be before (b) and after (e) all the sheets you want to take into account in the formula.

Put `=sum3D()` in cells you want to add (same place as the number you want to add in the differents tabs)

Put this custom function in your script editor

```
function sum3D() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var shs = ss.getSheets();
  var rng = ss.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell().getA1Notation()
  var sh1 = ss.getSheetByName('b').getIndex()
  var sh2 = ss.getSheetByName('e').getIndex()
  var result = 0
  for (var i = sh1; i < sh2; i++) {
    result += shs[i].getRange(rng).getValue()
  }
  return result
}
```

you can add a dummy argument as a check-box to actualize the computation `=sum3D(checkbox)`